# Check invocation static method on Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, static

I have some static method:

```
class WebUtils {
    static httpPostRequest(String url, Map data, Map headers) {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

And service:

```
class ChatService {
    void sendMessage(String text) {
        //some preparing code
        WebUtils.httpPostRequest(url, data, headers)
    } 
}
```

Now I want to check invocation of static method in the service by unit-test. Somehow like this:

```
void "test sending message"() {
    given:
        String text = 'Test'
        def mockedWebUtils = Mock(WebUtils)

    when:
        service.sendMessage(message)

    then:
        1*mockedWebUtils.httpPostRequest(_, [text: message], _)
}
```

But code above is not working. Is there legal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is using `GroovyMock` instead `Mock`:

```
void "test sending message"() {
    given:
        String text = 'Test'
        GroovyMock(global:true, WebUtils)

    when:
        service.sendMessage(text)

    then:
        1*WebUtils.httpPostRequest(_, [text: text], _)
}
```

I've found here:http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3-RC1/interaction_based_testing.html#_mocking_static_methods

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
void "test sending message"() {
    given:
        WebUtils.metaClass.static.httpPostRequest = { String url, Map data, Map headers ->
            return 'done' // you can do what you want here, just returning a string as example
        }
    when:
        service.sendMessage( 'Test' )
    then:
        1
        // test for something your method has done
}
```

Comment: I need not to replace the answer, but to check invocation with certain parameters.